# can you use fully fledged for person?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives, synonyms

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question, but i need an adjective to describe myself in my resume.
I'm trying to tell that I have solid experience on my field but not just in a couple of topics, neither in a subject. I'm someone who have experienced any relevant subjects on my field. I feel like i can use "wholly" but at the end that doesn't sound right. 
What should I call myself?

Comment: yes, yes. i'm a humble person :)

Comment: Fully-fledged might backfire. It means having the necessary feathers for flight. If you say I'm a fully-fledged X, it could sound like you are a proud recent graduate. Perhaps possess a wide-ranging knowledge of... Can you give a sample sentence with a blank? It might help to get you more accurate answers.

Comment: I use a sentence emphasizing experience, rather than fledging. The latter makes me think of young birds; which has *nothing* to do with the hiring process.  Technically, your usage is correct, but I think, tactically, it's wrong for the situation.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger i feel the same that it's wrong for situation.

Comment: @SConroy "wide-randing knowledge of software solutions" sounds just vague and somehow unconvincing to someone who needs a software development manager.

Comment: It would good to provide that info in the question too. Your own word 'solid' might be useful. Or you could expand. 'I have and indepth knowledge in...' Or 'I am fully versed in'...

Comment: but these are still not the ones i'm looking for.  'I have indepth knowledge in *software development*' I'm fully versed in *software management*' are still covering subjects, not whole software business. I don't know maybe there is no way of saying that without sound incompotent. Thanks for the effort again @SConroy

Comment: @Ozgur It's hard to know exactly what you are looking for. Is it one word for a person who has indepth knowledge and experience of all areas of the software business?

Comment: Depends.  Were you a member of the Junior Birdmen when you were a kid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**full fledged**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/75327?rskey=tPIR3b&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid3537016)

> fig. fully developed or qualified; having the fullest set of
>   credentials or qualifying characteristics

As in:

2002   New Yorker 25 Nov.

> He became, at the age of seventeen, a full-fledged crime reporter on
>   the New York Evening Graphic.

My sense is that a person can be **fully fledged** in the figurative as per the above definition.

Comment: maybe not the one i'm looking for, but the answer what i asked for though i marked as the answer.